# Openshift - How do I append ConfigMap value inside my YAML block chomping indicator

Tags: java, yaml, openshift

I have a ConfigMap like this:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: my-namespace
  .....
  labels:
    app: my-service
data:
  SPECIAL_NAME: Tom
  .....
```

I am trying to use the value of `SPECIAL_NAME` in my Deployment.yaml container which holds a block chomping indicator string like below but not able to do it successfully:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      ...
  template:
    metadata:
      ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-service
          image: 'myservice.myrepo.com/my-service:latest'
          env:
            - name: USERS
              value: >-
                -javaagent:/opt/project/javaagent.jar
                -Users.exist=true
                -Users.first=John
                -Users.specialone=SPECIAL_NAME
                ...
```

I tried like this but it doesn't work and I believe it shouldn't either.

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      ...
  template:
    metadata:
      ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-service
          image: 'myservice.myrepo.com/my-service:latest'
          env:
            - name: USERS
              value: >-
                -javaagent:/opt/project/javaagent.jar
                -Users.exist=true
                -Users.first=John
                ...
            - name: Users.specialone
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: my-service
                  key: SPECIAL_NAME
```

Comment: Try exchange file name from `Deployment.yaml` to `deployment.yml`

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh explain why please?

Answer (score 0):

Your ConfigMap is not valid

Check the [k8s ConfigMap doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/)

A valid ConfigMap would be (with the`"data"`stanza):

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: my-namespace
  .....
  labels:
    app: my-service
data:
  SPECIAL_NAME: Tom
  .....
```

Your deployment is not valid either. it should be:

```
- name: Users.specialone
  valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
          name: my-service
          key: SPECIAL_NAME
```

Also, depending on where you run k8s,`"Users.specialone"`could not be a valid environment variable name (because of the dot '.')

Check https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/f2ddd60eb9e7e9e29f7a105a9a8fa020042e8e52/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L923-L924

and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/f2ddd60eb9e7e9e29f7a105a9a8fa020042e8e52/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L42-L46

Comment: Thank you for pointing them out. Regarding the `configMapRef` i was looking at here: https://releasehub.com/blog/kubernetes-environment-variables
So does this mean therte is still no way of using configMap inside `- name: USERS
              value: >-....` ?